# NodeJS `"imports"` field on `package.json` for more than 1 file-tree level

Tags: node.js

I try to convert some references on my node projects to Node 19. In particular, the feature "imports" on the file `package.json` made me wonder on how to import files with an alias.

**Example**: For a project with source folder `src` with folders `fruits` and `vegetables`, I add the configuration on json content first-order key-values.

```
"imports": {
  "#fruits/*": "./src/fruits/*.js",
  "#fruits/*.js": "./src/fruits/*.js",
  "#vegetables/*": "./src/vegetables/*.js",
  "#vegetables/*.js": "./src/vegetables/*.js",
},
```

With that, I am able to use `import * from "#fruits/fruits.js"` or `import * from "#vegetables/vegetables.js"`

By experience, I learned that I cannot user it more than 1 level of folder-tree level. It means, in case there is still a folder `src/fruits/pseudo`, I am unable to use `import * from "#fruits/pseudo/pseudofruits.js"`. Is this correct or should I be able to import `pseudofruits` from the alias?

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation on [subpath patterns](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-patterns):

> `*` maps expose nested subpaths as it is a string replacement syntax only.

If you want to exclude specific subdirectories, you can set them to `null`. Unfortunately this would need to be done for each individual subdirectory.

```
"imports": {
  "#fruits/*": "./src/fruits/*.js",
  "#fruits/*.js": "./src/fruits/*.js",
  "#fruits/pseudo/*": null
}
```